# Strange behavior of a Windows.Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have an application in Windows.Forms with a main EXE module and various dlls.
I compile everything, copy the executable and dlls, run the program and open a Forms contained in one of the dlls, which opens regularly.
So far so normal. Then DELETE the dll from the disk, run the program, open the forms contained in the dll that I deleted and IT OPENS ITSELF !!! But how??? I have deleted the dll, I expect an exception of the type file not found or null references and instead it opens?
I have not incorporated the dlls, as one might think, so they are not found in the exe, unless Visual Studio makes its comfortable despite the instructions.
How can such a thing happen?

UPDATE.
I have deleted ALL dlls and the program continues to work. It appears to have incorporated all the dlls. I must say that this is a single solution, which contains an EXE project and 5 DLL projects, but why does it include everything in the executable in the compilation?

Comment: No, it's not like that, I just copied the files, I didn't use an installer. Sorry if I didn't specify it

Comment: Code that isn't there can't be run. So either the forms you show _aren't_ actually in your DLLs despite the fact that you believe them to be, or you're not running the program from where you think you are, or (some other version of) the DLLs are loaded from the GAC instead, or, or, or. Start by analyzing your code (or rather, creating a [mre]) to see where the forms are coming from. If you really believe them to be loaded from the DLLs, enable fusion logging to see where the assemblies are loaded from.

Comment: Perhaps they may be found in GAC. What are these DLLs? Are you using them by accessing objects or instantiating some?

Comment: The form I open is for sure in the dll. I think Visual Studio 2010 is incorporating dlls into the exe file. I see it because the dimensions have grown. I'm pretty sure this is the reason, but I don't understand why, maybe because they are all in the same solution as the exe file?
The process is simple: I have a project compiled as a windows application and all the Forms inserted in other dll projects.